# Aggregating a Key/Value list in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

General problem is that I've created a Name/Value mapping in elastic search to deal with a potentially huge user input of tags - as opposed to allowing an open schema where people can just create documents with new properties.

I've got an elastic search mapping that looks like this:

```
           "Tags" : {
              "properties" : {
                 "Value" : {
                    "analyzer" : "keyword",
                    "type" : "string"
                 },
                 "Name" : {
                    "analyzer" : "keyword",
                    "type" : "string"
                 }
              }
           },
```

With records that look like this

```
           "Tags" : [
              {
                 "Name" : "group",
                 "Value" : "foobar"
              },
              {
                 "Name" : "season",
                 "Value" : "winter"
              }
           ],
```

What I'm trying to do with an elastic search query is to write a script that will aggregate only the season entries.

```
...  
"script" : "for (int i = 0; i < doc['Tags.Value'].values.length; i++) { 
         if (doc['Tags.Value'].values[i] == 'season') {
              return doc['Tags.Names'].values[i]
          } }"
...
```

I've gone through about 200 permutations of the above script and it's not quite returning the results that I would like to see.

Comment: What output are  you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Tags` field should be `nested` so that you can write a `nested` query to only select the `season` tags and then you can aggregate on those values only. That would allow you to ditch that script which is going to perform very badly if you have a huge amount of tags.

So your mapping needs to look like this:

```
       "Tags" : {
          "type": "nested",                    <---- add this
          "properties" : {
             "Value" : {
                "analyzer" : "keyword",
                "type" : "string"
             },
             "Name" : {
                "analyzer" : "keyword",
                "type" : "string"
             }
          }
       },
```

Then your query should include a `nested` clause on the `season` tag names, so that your `terms` aggregation can simply work on those values.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "Tags",
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "Tags.Name": "season"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "season_tags": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "Tags"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "season_values": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Tags.Value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It used to be a nested document.  How would you aggregate against two Tag fields?  group then season ?

Comment: Why "used to" be? Why did you change?

Comment: I was struggling trying to get the nested aggregation to work, so that's why I changed. I've changed it back and will be trying this out.

Though in thinking about it, how would aggregate on two of these fields if you wanted a "group" and "season" aggregation you couldn't filter in your example.  Maybe you could, I just need to try...

Comment: Not sure I understand, but let me know how it works out for you and we'll figure out.

Comment: The solution does not seem to be working for elasticsearch 6.   Does anyone got it to work for v6 ?

Comment: @sukrit007 feel free to create a new question referencing this one with your exact issue and a way for people to reproduce your problem.